# How to make mongodump from AWS Lambda function in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mongodump

I need to dump mongo data base from AWS Lambda function and store the dump folder on AWS S3 with node.js.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this project on github : [lambda-mongocluster-s3](https://github.com/llangit/lambda-mongocluster-s3)

It includes the mongodump binary, where you can specify the `MONGODUMP_OPTIONS` without the `--out` param it'll zip the output and store it on S3